# Every reboot alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf and i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf are dropped to mesa

Tags: nvidia, ati, fglrx, update-alternatives

That is.

I've removed nvidia drivers with running `nvidia-installer.run --uninstall`, rebooted, installed `fglrx`, rebooted again and found that `amdconfig is not found`. I've googled the solution and tried to do

```
sudo update-alternatives --auto i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo update-alternatives --auto x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

Then I checked the result with `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep gl_conf` and everything was fine. But after reboot I see again that both alternatives are set to mesa again:

```
i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf         manual   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf      auto     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf
x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf       manual   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
```

I've found the `/var/log/alternatives.log` and see that something explicitly sets these links during the boot:

```
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 18:37:50: run with --auto i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 18:37:57: run with --auto i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:28: run with --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:28: status of link group /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf set to manual
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:28: link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf updated to point to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:38: run with --set i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:38: status of link group /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf set to manual
update-alternatives 2014-06-09 22:39:38: link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf updated to point to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
```

How can I determine what does that? Maybe some part of nvidia driver was not correctly removed with `--uninstall` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479504/ubuntu-14-04-crashes-after-installing-nvidia-331-or-nvidia-current-driver-gtx-7) regarding uninstalling nvidia drivers, it is about "installing" but also contains how to remove what is present before that - might be you have missed something.

Comment: I've installed drivers not from the repository but from the official site, so they were not under package control

Comment: 'dpkg --list | grep nvidia' to check if there is something remaining. I did never succeed in installing just the "official" *.run archive, I always had to add something from the repositories too.

Comment: You were right... `apt-get purge "nvidia*"` solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: the link is broken, can anyone remember what was in it?

Comment: It was obsolete info.